# Multiple cucumber report is displaying the error message with special characters

Tags: typescript, cucumber, playwright

In the multiple cucumber report, the error messages are displayed with special charaters. How can i get with proper format. I am learning Playwright+Typescript+CucumberJs and generating the reports for the test.

[image]

Comment: They're ansi color codes. Have a look at https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/13522 to see how you can get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Run your tests in no color mode:

### Windows:

```
set FORCE_COLOR=false && npx playwright test
```

### MacOS/Linux

```bash
FORCE_COLOR=false npx playwright test
```

P.S. Use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) if you work both on linux and windows shell.

```bash
cross-env FORCE_COLOR=false npx playwright test
```

Comment: it is not working, i get this error. `'FORCE_COLOR' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I tried in both windows 10 and 11.

Comment: i wish to like the answer, but after trying your updated answer still i am seeing the same issue. i have my test script like this `"test": "set FORCE_COLOR=false && npm run suite && npm run report"`.

Comment: Where do you run it? what os? cmd, ps?

Comment: i tried in both Wind 10 and 11. command as above.

Comment: `npm i cross-env` in project, add `cross-env FORCE_COLOR=false npx playwright test` to commands